# How to use an external javascript file in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I wrote a script to hide and show a loader for my asp.net web application. The script works great when placed inline. I tried to extract the script to an external file and received the following error:

**Error:** The value of the property 'Pausing' is null or undefined, not a Function object

I tried to look up the error, but I was unable to find a solution to the problem. I am new to asp.net so it may be that I'm not sure how to search for the right question.

My inline code that works is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Pausing() {
        window.setTimeout(ShowLoader, 1);
    }

    function ShowLoader() {
        if ((typeof Page_IsValid === 'undefined') || 
            (Page_IsValid != null && Page_IsValid)) {
            var i = document.getElementById("loader");
            var img = document.getElementById("img");
            i.style.display = "block";
            setTimeout("document.images['img'].src=document.images['img'].src", 10);
            Endpausing();
        }
    }

    function HideLoader() {
        var i = document.getElementById("loader");
        i.style.display = "none";
    }

    function Endpausing() {
        window.setTimeout(HideLoader, 4000);
    }
</script>
```

The event call is attached to an asp:button control below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGetReport" runat="server" OnClick="btnGetReport_Click" OnClientClick="Pausing();" />
```

I removed the inline script and replaced with this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Loader.js"></script>
```

Added script to external file:

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {

    function Pausing() {
        window.setTimeout(ShowLoader, 1);
    }

    function ShowLoader() {
        if ((typeof Page_IsValid === 'undefined') ||      // asp page has no validator
                (Page_IsValid != null && Page_IsValid)) {
            var i = document.getElementById("loader");
            var img = document.getElementById("img");
            i.style.display = "block";
            setTimeout("document.images['img'].src=document.images['img'].src", 10);
            Endpausing();
        }
    }

    function HideLoader() {
        var i = document.getElementById("loader");
        i.style.display = "none";
    }

    function Endpausing() {
        window.setTimeout(HideLoader, 4000);
    }
}
```

Then I receive the previously mentioned error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: make your inline code the same as the external file, and see if you get the same error.  Go from there with your debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use ResolveUrl to call your script files like this

Lets assume your script is in Script folder  of your root path with a file Name  as MyScriptFile.js

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl ("~/Scripts/MyScriptFile.js") %>"></script>
```

EDIT : you can use ResolveUrl or ResolveClientUrl  based on your needs

ResolveUrl creates the URL relative to the root where as 
ResolveClientUrl creates the URL relative to the current page.

Comment: I added this into my script src attribute and I am still receiving the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried with ResolveClientUrl instead of ResolveUrl as well ?

Comment: Just checked why do you using initAll i.e.., initAll() function? put the pausing function out of it intiAll()

Comment: I just tried ResolveClientUrl and removing initAll() function with every combination. Still a no joy!

Comment: First I advice you to create another js file external with a test function and alert inside it and try checking if you can see the alert.

Comment: Ok, AWESOME! It was the initAll() function. I missed a bracket at the end when I tried it earlier. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, dont forget to giveme the green right as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question : How to use an external javascript file in asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyz.com/test.js"></script>
```